How to make pytorch cross entropy work with a TorchGeo dataset
I'm trying to train a PyTorch model on some geographic data so I'm using a single band RasterDataset from TorchGeo with a VectorDataset to load in the targets, this gives me a batch with (['crs', 'bbox', 'image', 'mask']) as keys where the image is the raster data and the mask is the vector polygon rasterised.
Now when I try to run a resnet18 model with ce loss function, I get the following error:
File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/strategies/strategy.py:412, in Strategy.validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs)
    410 if self.model != self.lightning_module:
    411     return self._forward_redirection(self.model, self.lightning_module, "validation_step", *args, **kwargs)
--> 412 return self.lightning_module.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchgeo/trainers/classification.py:201, in ClassificationTask.validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    199 y = batch["label"]
    200 y_hat = self(x)
--> 201 loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
    202 self.log("val_loss", loss)
    203 self.val_metrics(y_hat, y)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1179, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1178 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1179     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1180                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1181                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3059, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3057 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3058     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3059 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'target' (position 2) must be Tensor, not list

To me the problem seems to be that my batch doesn't have a label item, so I modified my dataset to add one first as a copy of the mask, which gives:
File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchgeo/trainers/classification.py:201, in ClassificationTask.validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    199 y = batch["label"]
    200 y_hat = self(x)
--> 201 loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
    202 self.log("val_loss", loss)
    203 self.val_metrics(y_hat, y)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1179, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1178 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1179     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1180                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1181                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3059, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3057 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3058     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3059 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

So then I tried a torch.IntTensor([0, 1]) as there are only 2 classes, but that gives:
File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchgeo/trainers/classification.py:201, in ClassificationTask.validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    199 y = batch["label"]
    200 y_hat = self(x)
--> 201 loss = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
    202 self.log("val_loss", loss)
    203 self.val_metrics(y_hat, y)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:1179, in CrossEntropyLoss.forward(self, input, target)
   1178 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
-> 1179     return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
   1180                            ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction,
   1181                            label_smoothing=self.label_smoothing)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:3059, in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3057 if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3058     reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3059 return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Int

So then I tried torch.FloatTensor([0.0, 1.0]) even though they aren't really class probabilities but that fails with, so I've moved forward but I don't think this is the right direction:
File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchgeo/trainers/classification.py:183, in ClassificationTask.training_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
    181 loss: Tensor = self.criterion(y_hat, y)
    182 self.log("train_loss", loss)
--> 183 self.train_metrics(y_hat, y)
    184 self.log_dict(self.train_metrics)
    186 return loss

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/collections.py:198, in MetricCollection.forward(self, *args, **kwargs)
    190 @torch.jit.unused
    191 def forward(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    192     """Call forward for each metric sequentially.
    193 
    194     Positional arguments (args) will be passed to every metric in the collection, while keyword arguments (kwargs)
    195     will be filtered based on the signature of the individual metric.
    196 
    197     """
--> 198     return self._compute_and_reduce("forward", *args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/collections.py:335, in MetricCollection._compute_and_reduce(self, method_name, *args, **kwargs)
    333     res = m.compute()
    334 elif method_name == "forward":
--> 335     res = m(*args, **m._filter_kwargs(**kwargs))
    336 else:
    337     raise ValueError("method_name should be either 'compute' or 'forward', but got {method_name}")

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1511, in Module._wrapped_call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1509     return self._compiled_call_impl(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[misc]
   1510 else:
-> 1511     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1520, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1515 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1516 # this function, and just call forward.
   1517 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1518         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1519         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1520     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1522 try:
   1523     result = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py:303, in Metric.forward(self, *args, **kwargs)
    301     self._forward_cache = self._forward_full_state_update(*args, **kwargs)
    302 else:
--> 303     self._forward_cache = self._forward_reduce_state_update(*args, **kwargs)
    305 return self._forward_cache

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py:372, in Metric._forward_reduce_state_update(self, *args, **kwargs)
    369 self._enable_grad = True  # allow grads for batch computation
    371 # calculate batch state and compute batch value
--> 372 self.update(*args, **kwargs)
    373 batch_val = self.compute()
    375 # reduce batch and global state

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py:475, in Metric._wrap_update.<locals>.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    467         if "Expected all tensors to be on" in str(err):
    468             raise RuntimeError(
    469                 "Encountered different devices in metric calculation (see stacktrace for details)."
    470                 " This could be due to the metric class not being on the same device as input."
   (...)
    473                 " device corresponds to the device of the input."
    474             ) from err
--> 475         raise err
    477 if self.compute_on_cpu:
    478     self._move_list_states_to_cpu()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/metric.py:465, in Metric._wrap_update.<locals>.wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    463 with torch.set_grad_enabled(self._enable_grad):
    464     try:
--> 465         update(*args, **kwargs)
    466     except RuntimeError as err:
    467         if "Expected all tensors to be on" in str(err):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/classification/stat_scores.py:335, in MulticlassStatScores.update(self, preds, target)
    331     _multiclass_stat_scores_tensor_validation(
    332         preds, target, self.num_classes, self.multidim_average, self.ignore_index
    333     )
    334 preds, target = _multiclass_stat_scores_format(preds, target, self.top_k)
--> 335 tp, fp, tn, fn = _multiclass_stat_scores_update(
    336     preds, target, self.num_classes, self.top_k, self.average, self.multidim_average, self.ignore_index
    337 )
    338 self._update_state(tp, fp, tn, fn)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/functional/classification/stat_scores.py:413, in _multiclass_stat_scores_update(preds, target, num_classes, top_k, average, multidim_average, ignore_index)
    411     target = target[idx]
    412 unique_mapping = target.to(torch.long) * num_classes + preds.to(torch.long)
--> 413 bins = _bincount(unique_mapping, minlength=num_classes**2)
    414 confmat = bins.reshape(num_classes, num_classes)
    415 tp = confmat.diag()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/torchgeo/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torchmetrics/utilities/data.py:207, in _bincount(x, minlength)
    204     mesh = torch.arange(minlength, device=x.device).repeat(len(x), 1)
    205     return torch.eq(x.reshape(-1, 1), mesh).sum(dim=0)
--> 207 return torch.bincount(x, minlength=minlength)

RuntimeError: bincount only supports 1-d non-negative integral inputs.

